# Display parameters in cppcms GET or POST request

Tags: c++, cppcms

How to get the parameters list from cppcms GET or POST URI's ?
For example :

`GET uri_servicename?param1=value1`

I want to extract this param1 and value1 if they exist in the URI.

Edit: I wanted to save them as variables.

Comment: What do you mean extract params? Are you looking to handle dispatching and mapping? Are you looking to save them as variables?

Comment: I wanted to save them as variables. Got to know a method called query_string() in cppcms/http_request.h header to get all parameters and values. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I edited the question for specific requirement. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got to know a method called query_string() under <cppcms/http_request.h> which gives the whole query string including all parameters and values in the http request.

We can use it as:

```
std::string paramlist = request().query_string();
```

Reference:

http://cppcms.com/cppcms_ref/latest/classcppcms_1_1http_1_1request.html

Comment: Better approach is: http://cppcms.com/wikipp/en/page/cppcms_1x_forms